# Discontinuous/Continuous Function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I am having a hard time coming up with a function for this question. Any ideas?

A function that is discontinuous at even natural numbers and continuous everywhere else.

Comment: The indicator function of even naturals....

Answer (score 1):

How about $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{$x$ is an even natural number}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\\ \end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac x2\right\rfloor+\left|\left\lfloor\frac x2\right\rfloor\right|$$